# Text align in android editext

Tags: android

I have the following component in my main.xml

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/result"  
        android:singleLine="true"   
        android:layout_span="3"  
        android:text="0.0" />
```

How do i align the text to the right , as it is aligned to the left by default.

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:gravity="right"` to EditText

Answer (score 0):

Add below tag

```
  android:gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="end"
```

Add these two properties to your EditText.